# Why aren't my inputs formatting correctly in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form, which is created dynamically, which is the reason for the jquery (It's easier).  I am trying to figure out why the input fields are not formatting correctly.

I have just changed the way it is formatted, from being in a table, to a more bootstrappy way of things, and this way, only the input fields I put icons on are working properly.  The jQuery works fine when I have the same fields in the table.

What am I doing wrong?

There is also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28tudtm1/3/).

Here is a representative portion of the form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="first_name" class="sr-only">*
      <label for="id_first_name">First name:</label>
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" required maxlength="50" required id="id_first_name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="last_name" class="sr-only">*
      <label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label>
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" required maxlength="50" required id="id_last_name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="phone" class="sr-only">*
      <label for="id_phone">Phone:</label>
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="id_phone" name="phone" type="tel" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since my fields are created dynamically, and their attributes are more work to get at, I have used jQuery to add the `form-control` class to the inputs, and some other minor things.

Here is that code:

```
$("input[type='email']").parent('div:first').prepend('<div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>');
$("input[type='tel']").parent('div:first').prepend('<div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></div>');
$('input').addClass('form-control').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $label = $('label[for="' + $this.attr('id') + '"]');
    $this.attr('placeholder', $label.text().slice(0, -1));
});
$('select').addClass('form-control');
```

Comment: This is because you have your `text` fields wrapped inside of `<div class="input-group">` but aren't adding any  `.input-group-addon` as you are with your **email** and **tel** fields. Are you able to change the HTML structure to remove the input-group divs because you can simply add them to the inputs that need them with jQuery as well. (Also, you can't nest a label inside of another label, it's not valid: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834755/standards-on-behaviour-of-nested-labels) for more info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have your regular inputs inside of an `input-group` element but are not adding an icon inside with the input which it expects.

For any input that wont have an icon, change your html from:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" required maxlength="50" required id="id_first_name">
</div>
```

To simply:

```
  <input type="text" name="first_name" required maxlength="50" required id="id_first_name">
```

and the formatting will work as expected.

#### [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/63/)

Comment: Worked great, and I appreciate the explanation of why it wasn't working.